# Using angular to turn a multi-dimensional array into a multi list

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

js` and I would like to repeat an array into a list

**From this:** 
This is in the Service:

```
var Response= [
        ["Article One"],
        ["Article Two"],
        ["Article Three"],
        ["Article Images", ["Images 1", "Images 2", "Images 3"] ],
        ["Article Five"]
    ];
```

And calling the Object from the Controller:

```
$scope.Response = function () {
        return ArtikelSucheService.Response;
    };
```

**I want to repeat it like this:**

```
<ul ng-repeat="Article in Response()">
        <li>Article One</li>
        <li>Article Two</li>
        <li>Article Three</li>
        <li>Images 
            <ul ng-repeat="What must stay here?">
                <li>Images 1</li>
                <li>Images 2</li>
                <li>Images 3</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Article Five</li>
   </ul>
```

I don't know, how can I repeat an array in an array.
Response is an array. And in Response there are x images.
1 article can have many images.

Can anybody help me out?

Answer (score 0):

```
var Response1= [
        ["Article One"],
        ["Article Two"],
        ["Article Three"],
        ["Article Images", ["Images 1", "Images 2", "Images 3"] ],
        ["Article Five"]
];
```

and in html use below template

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat='option in responses1'>
      {{option[0]}}
      <ul>
      <li ng-repeat='suboption in option[1]'>{{suboption}}</li>
    </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
```

working fiddle 
http://jsfiddle.net/jw5Qf/1/

Comment: there is no need to add the empty arrays. At least as of 1.0.4 if the source array is undefined then ng-repeat will not execute

Answer (score 0):

May be like following?

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="Article in Response()">
    {{ Article[0] }}
    <ul ng-show="Article[1]">
      <li ng-repeat="img in Article[1]">{{ img }}</li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```